# How to connect sql server 2017 from eclipse oxygen

Tags: sql, eclipse-plugin, sql-server-2016

I am trying to connect SQL Server 2017 from eclipse oxygen on windows 10.

I am following this link https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/02/how-to-connect-to-microsoft-sql-server-from-Eclipse.html

I also have downloaded sqljdbc_6.4.0.0_enu. I am stuck in a step where it doesn't show latest version. Which option to select for next step

Please look at screenshot 
[option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLrr5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I always pick "Other Driver" and then I add my JDBC driver jar file in the "JAR List" tab. It always works for me.

Comment: I am using sql server 2017 but this server is not in the list. All are showing old version. My question is how to install right driver for sql2017